# Streaming audio and video to VLC with ffmpeg and ffserver

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, vlc-media-player, webcam

I'm trying to set up a webcam with a raspberry pi 2 that I can view from VLC media player on another computer. I [followed the tutorial here](http://sirlagz.net/2013/01/07/how-to-stream-a-webcam-from-the-raspberry-pi-part-3/) to get video only working, but his [other tutorial that involved audio](http://sirlagz.net/2013/03/10/quickie-streaming-audio-and-video-from-a-webcam-on-the-raspberry-pi/) didn't work for me.

Here are the settings that worked for me with video for `ffserver -f webcam.conf`:

```
HTTPPort 80
HTTPBindAddress 0.0.0.0
MaxClients 10
MaxBandwidth 50000

<Feed webcam.ffm>

File /tmp/web.ffm
FileMaxSize 10M

</Feed>

<Stream webcam.mjpeg>

Feed webcam.ffm
Format mjpeg
VideoSize 320x240
VideoFrameRate 10
VideoBitRate 20000
VideoQMin 1
VideoQMax 10

</Stream>

<Stream stat.html>
Format status
</Stream>
```

Then I was able to run it with this command:

```
ffserver -f webcam.conf & ffmpeg -v verbose -r 5 -s 320x240 \
-f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 http://0.0.0.0/webcam.ffm
```

I tried a couple different file formats to get audio working, the tutorial suggests avi, but that didn't work and the [ffmpeg documentation](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffserver.html#How-do-I-make-it-work_003f) explains why it shouldn't. So I tried `asf`, `rm`, and `mpeg` as well. With `asf` I was able to get a grey screen in VLC, but no real video or audio. Here's the configuration changes:

```
<Stream test.asf>
Feed webcam.ffm
Format asf
VideoCodec msmpeg4v2
VideoFrameRate 15
VideoSize vga
VideoBitRate 320
VideoBufferSize 40
VideoGopSize 15
AudioBitRate 64
# StartSendOnKey
</Stream>
```

And the command I tried to run it:

```
ffmpeg -thread_queue_size 512 -v verbose -f video4linux2 -r 3 \
-i /dev/video0 -f alsa -ac 1 -i hw:1 http:/0.0.0.0/webcam.ffm
```

I've read some articles that mentioned a delay, but I kept it running for at least 30 minutes and got nothing but grey. I feel like I'm just not getting the right combination of settings between my ffserver config and the ffmpeg command I'm running to stream it. What am I missing? Alternatively, is there a different media player I should be using to view my streams?